What are Shreds in Solana?
The documentation at https://solana.com/docs/terminology#shred puts the definition for a shred as:

A fraction of a block; the smallest unit sent between validators.

But this definition is not really precise and it leaves room for more questions.
It says a shred is a fraction of a block...is this fraction then 1/2 of a block? 1/3? 1/4? or 1/1000 that qualifies as a shred?
Also I know a block contains transactions. If a shred is a fraction of a block, I assume a shred also contains transactions. How many transactions then does a shred contains?
It says it is the smallest unit sent between validators. This gives the impression that "how small" is somewhat defined. Because if not, then how do one know if what is being sent is smaller than the smallest unit or greater than the smallest unit. So the question is, in what terms is the smallest unit defined? The number of transactions a shred contains? or the fraction of the block it is?
Also it is possible for Shreds to contains parts of a transaction? I ask because I am imagining a shred as being a chopped up block. In such metaphor is it guaranteed that transactions would always be atomic? Or the data that makes up one transaction can be split up between two or more shreds?

The source code will probably give the best info, unfortunately: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/d22e8e36d84ec4fad88b97cb633b704d1a90e197/ledger/src/shred.rs#L1
A "shred" is the smallest unit of a block. Blocks can be quite large, with thousands of transactions, but validators communicate in MTU-sized packets, which gives roughly 1232 bytes of payload. This choice was made to avoid packet fragmentation at the network level.
Since transactions don't all have the same size, there's no guarantee of how many can fit in a shred. If all the transactions are small, then it's possible to fit many transactions in a shred. But you may only be able to fit one large transaction in a shred. Since there's additional overhead for a shred though, one transaction may span multiple shreds. This does not break atomicity though, since shreds span multiple entries, and not transactions: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/entry/src/entry.rs
A block is replayed in entries, so if a validator hasn't received all shreds for an entry, it won't replay any of the transactions it. (I might be wrong on this last part, but that's what my intuition tells me.)
